# COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_BREAK macros doesn't work

Tags: c++, debugging, com, atl

I have an ATL class. I'd like to know when `QueryInterface` of this class is called in order to remove memory leaks.

I added `COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_BREAK`'s in the `COM_MAP`, now it looks like:

```
BEGIN_COM_MAP( CMyClass )
      COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY( IFace1 )
      COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY( IFace2 )

      //COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_BREAK(IUnknown) // i included this too
      COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_BREAK( IFace1 )
      COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_BREAK( IFace2 )
END_COM_MAP()
```

When i start to debug (pressing F5) i have no breakpoint after the QI operation. I'm sure that QI is called because `_ATL_DEBUG_INTERFACES` shows a leak in the output window

`ATL: QIThunk - 4           LEAK    :   Object = 0x02150CC0 Refcount = 1    MaxRefCount = 2 CMyClass - IUnknown`

What should I do in order to have a breakpoint stopped at QI calling?

Thank you.

Comment: `COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_BREAK(IUnknown)` only breaks if queried for `IID_IUnknown` **specifically**. It doesn't mean "break when queried via `IUnknown::QueryInterface` "

Comment: Could you explain more detaily? Does it mean i can't catch the moment when ``IFace1`` of my class is queried?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "queried"? Do you mean `IFace1::QueryInterface(any_IID)` or `IAny::QueryInterface(IID_IFace1)` ?

Comment: The second one.
 
``p.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CMyClass))
IFace1Ptr p2 = p; // p->QueryInterface(IFace1, &p2) <--- I want to break in this moment``

Comment: Well, it's actually both: `IFace1Ptr->QueryInterface` is going to call `IFace::QueryInterface`. This is certainly allowed, but only performs an `AddRef`.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly you want a breakpoint on the AddRef() call, not the QI call.  Yes, painful, finding reference counting bugs in the client code from the server doesn't work very well if you use the ATL wrappers.  Not otherwise fundamentally different from trying to diagnose memory leaks by setting a breakpoint on the new/delete operators, that doesn't work well either.

You can set a breakpoint on the InternalAddRef() method inside atlcom.h.  But it can be noisy and it may cause the debugger to go catatonic for a while if you have a lot of interfaces in your server.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i have a big project containing many ATL classes, so, as you said, i get tons of breaks.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem with `COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_FUNC_BLIND` macro like this:

```
BEGIN_COM_MAP(CMyClass)
  COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDummy) // NB!: this has to go before COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_FUNC_BLIND
  COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_FUNC_BLIND(0, MyQueryInterface)
END_COM_MAP
```

`MyQueryInterface` is a function called every time an interface is querying.

My function is:

```
QueryInterfaceFunc ( void* pv, REFIID riid, LPVOID* ppv, DWORD dw )
{
  if (riid == __uuidof(IFace1))
  {
    DebugBreak(); // Break here in the case of querying IFace1
  }
}
```